# Huwawei E173 USB dongle to user internet and send SMS (mandatory)

Tags: wireless

I use a pre paid Internet connection. To activate and deactivate packages I need to to the same using SMS. I understand I can just plug in the dongle and connect to the internet using the Ubuntu wireless connection manager. But I cannot send SMS.

I used to be able to do this in windows and I jurst shifted from Windows to ubuntu so I am a newbie.

In windows i had mobile partner but I cannot find it to Ubuntu. Should I "need" to find one? cant I send/receive SMS using a different software? Or is it the best to activate/deactivate my connection and send SMS using the Mobile Partner Software for Linux? where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modem-manager for sending and receiving sms from your modem.
You can install it from the software-center.
To install it from a terminal use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui
```

Regarding mobile partner you can follow the procedure in the following link to install it.:
http://linux2help.blogspot.in/2013/10/installing-mobile-partner-in-linux.html

Comment: isnt there a much responsive solution than that?